# Abstract or virtual method?

Tags: c#, .net

Whats recommended in an abstract class?

Have a virtual method returning null, or have an abstract method?

It is convenient and easy to have them returning null, as I don't have to do anything inheriting from the abstract class. But still, returning null is somewhat hard to understand if it is by purpose, error, or by design....

Are there any clear recommendations for this?

Comment: Of course, *anything* that isn't properly documented will be difficult to understand.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If returning null is a sensible and sane thing to do as a default behaviour (with supporting documentation), then perhaps `virtual` is fine. Likewise, if you can create a sensible default but just want to offer extensibility: `virtual`.

If the (concrete) class *cannot function* without a non-default implementation, then make it `abstract`. The casebook scenario here is `Stream` : without a sane implementation *where would the bytes come from?* (/go to).

Answer (score 2):

I have an abstract method if I demand the derived class provide functionality, and a virtual method returning null (or doing some default action) if I'm not so bothered.